# how to make typeconversion when struct contain interface and range that to get csv data

Tags: go

Situation is I have one interface inside struct now I have to range that data to get CSV format.
this is strut and interface

```
PaginatedListResponseDataRec struct {
TotalDBRecCnt  int         `json:"totalrecords"`    // total number of records exists in the database.
FilteredRecCnt int         `json:"filteredrecords"` // number of records filtered based on the search criteria
RecList        interface{} `json:"records"`         // list of filtered records
TodayDBRecCnt  int         `json:"todayrecords"`}
```

now in this struct RecList contained data that i want to display in CSV format.

```
isSuccess, responseData := dbAccess.GetJobList(reqFilterRec, clientID)
```

here responseData is type of PaginatedListResponseDataRec struct

```
    v := reflect.ValueOf(responseData.RecList)
values := make([]interface{}, v.NumField())

for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    values[i] = v.Field(i).Interface()
}

fmt.Println("values: ", values)
```

this is the code which i'm using to range,
but this return error

```
exception: &runtime.TypeAssertionError{_interface:(*runtime._type)(0xa458e0), concrete:(*runtime._type)(0xa05960), asserted:(*runtime._type)(0xa05c60), missingMethod:""}
```

can anyone help..

Comment: Is an error returned or does your code panic? Presumably panicing: Which line panics? Presumably `values[i] = v.Field(i).Interface()` ? Try recovering that panic and format it with it's Error method.

Comment: From its name and from what you've described `RecList` does not seem to be a struct but a slice, or at the least an array. With that in mind if you read the documentation on [`NumField`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.NumField) you should get the your answer as to what's wrong. *"NumField returns the number of fields in the struct v. **It panics if v's Kind is not Struct**."*

Answer (score 0):

Slice/Array ranging with reflect isn't done with NumField and Field, those are used in structs. What you need is Len() and Index():

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(responseData.RecList)
values := make([]interface{}, v.Len())

for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
    values[i] = v.Index(i).Interface()
}

fmt.Println("values: ", values)
```

https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Len

https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Index